# How to make my high score change only when it is greater than the last score and always start it from zero in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform player;
public Text scoreText;
public Text HighScore;
void Start()
{

     
    HighScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FinalScore",0).ToString("0");
}

public void Update()
{
float position = player.position.z;
scoreText.text = position.ToString("0");
HighScoring();
}
public void HighScoring()
{
    float position = player.position.z;
    if (position > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FinalScore", 0))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FinalScore", (int)position);
    }
}
}
```

i am not able to increase my score when my score is greater than the last score instead it always shows the last game score and it is not starting from zero what can i do in this unity car race game.

Comment: Looks like a TYPO to me: You most probably wanted `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", (int)position);` not `FinalScore` ? Why is the `FinalScore` in PlayerPRefs at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the Z axis of the player but probably what's happening is your player is not even traveling to Z axis, that might be the reason why it's not working properly.

Instead of getting the `player.position.z`, you should save the player's start position by creating a variable with `Vector3 startPos;` to use it later because player's start position might not be 0 in the world space and that might give you wrong results.
Save the position with `startPos = player.position;` inside `void Start()`

Now we can get the distance between `startPos` and `player.position` using [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) which takes two Vector3 variables and returns the distance as a float.

But you can get negative values with this approach considering your car might be traveling to negative x or y axis, so you should put [Mathf.Abs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Abs.html) which returns the absolute value of a number that you give.

Combining all of this together, you can get the distance like this: `Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(startPos, player.position));`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text HighScore;
    Vector3 startPos;

    void Start()
    {
        startPos = player.position; //Get the starting position of the player
        HighScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FinalScore", 0).ToString("0");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        float distance = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(startPos, player.position)); //Get the distance between starting position and the current position
        scoreText.text = distance.ToString("0");
        HighScoring(distance);
    }
    public void HighScoring(float distance) //Calculating the distance again would be unnecesarry so we are taking it from here
    {
        if (distance > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FinalScore", 0))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FinalScore", (int)distance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).